# can't understand this jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to web development and am referring following link-

[tic tac toe javascript](https://mostafa-samir.github.io/Tic-Tac-Toe-AI/)

Please find below js, css and html file respectively.

We are not having any element with class="selected" but still project is running perfectly

```js
$(".level").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.click(function() {
    $('.selected').toggleClass('not-selected');
    $('.selected').toggleClass('selected');
    $this.toggleClass('not-selected');
    $this.toggleClass('selected');
    ai.level = $this.attr("id");
  });
});
```

```css
.level {
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: lightskyblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.not-selected {
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.not-selected:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class='difficulty'>
  <span class='level not-selected' id="blind">Blind</span>
  <span class='level not-selected' id="novice">Novice</span>
  <span class='level not-selected' id="master">Master!</span>
</div>
```

I am unable to understand this js.

**Please clear my two doubts-   1.use of click inside each  2.how .selected work in jquery
The snippet won't work cause i didn't add jquery to it.**

Comment: After first click on a .level-element you would have a .selected ($this.toggleClass('selected')).

Comment: It is a lot more complex that it needs to be. The outer `.each` could be easily omitted, for example

Comment: How come we were not getting any error when using $('.selected'), when at first time we were not having any element with selected class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle behavior - if the element has a class, the class will be removed. If the element hasn't got the class, the class will be added. In this case there are no elements with .select class, but it will be added after toggleClass('selected') executes. I commented every js line for you.

```
$(".level").each(function() { // for each element with class .level
    var $this = $(this); // save the current jQuery object in the loop in the $this variable
    $this.click(function() { // add a click event to the current object
      $('.selected').toggleClass('not-selected'); // for the elements with .selectd class toggle .not-selectd class
      $('.selected').toggleClass('selected'); // for the elements with .selectd class toggle .selectd class
      $this.toggleClass('not-selected'); // for the current elements toggle .not-selectd class
      $this.toggleClass('selected'); // for the current elements toggle .selectd class

      ai.level = $this.attr("id"); // ai not defined in current context, will give an error, but if was defined you would save current element id in ai.level
    });
});
```

This code could be written much easier and do the same. You don't need .selected class since there is no style for it in css

```js
$(".level").click(function(){ // click event for elements with class .level
  $(".level").addClass("not-selected"); // add .not-selected class to all .level elements
  $(this).removeClass("not-selected"); // remove not-selected class from the CURRENT clicked element
});
```

```css
.level {
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: lightskyblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.not-selected {
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.not-selected:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='difficulty'>
  <span class='level not-selected' id="blind">Blind</span>
  <span class='level not-selected' id="novice">Novice</span>
  <span class='level not-selected' id="master">Master!</span>
</div>
```

**Edit duo comments:**

1.use of click inside each

In your case you are getting objects $(".level") and iterating through them. Inside the loop you are assigning to the current element a click event listener. this is unneeded you can just do `$('.level').click(function(){});` with out iterating.

2. how .selected work in jquery

This is just a HTML class with no special behavior. You can just manage elements by it class. You can use any class you want like `.my-super-class-name` and use it. It's just a HTML attribute.

Comment: it should toggle ... your code doesn't toggle any more, it just selects

Comment: why iy should toggle? The behavior is the same. You can replace remove with toggle if you like it more tho

Comment: No your code won't unselect a clicked item if it had already been selected

Comment: yep, the code posted in the question won't do it aswell

Comment: I can't find any element with class selected. That's what question is all about . Refer control.js and index.html in mentioned link github project

Comment: At the page load there are no .selected class. It will be added after toggleClass executes

Comment: but what is the use of selected class when there is no css for selected class

Comment: It may be needed to use in JS later. In the short case you posted there is no use of it.

Comment: Ok maybe but how come we were not getting any error at first place when we were not having any element with selected class and we used this statement $('.selected').toggleClass('not-selected')

Comment: Because it doesn't cause any errors. The number of elements found will be 0 which means nothing will be toggled. If the element is not found jQuery won't return any errors.

Comment: Thanks sir for your comments, just clear two doubts-   1.use of click inside each  2.how .selected work in jquery

Comment: look the ending of my answer